# Does this Soyuz vehicle burn coal or oil? What is its official name?

Tags: fuel, identify-this-object, liquid-fuel, solid-fuel

This [tweet](https://twitter.com/marsrader/status/1151484833987796992) shows the image below and says:

> Soyuz rocket on its way to the launch pad (on a train of course).

**Question:** Does this Soyuz vehicle (a train engine) burn coal or oil? Does it have an official name?

[image: Soyuz rocket on its way to the launch pad (on a train of course) from https://twitter.com/marsrader/status/1151484833987796992]

Comment: There is no white steam visible, so it could not be a coal fired steam engine.

Comment: and no steam engine has ever looked like that.

Comment: If it was coal & subsequently steam, it would give an new meaning to Steam Punk. An interesting concept, steam power in the Space Age.

Comment: A coal fire does not produce so much soot. But a diesel engine accelerating from a very low speed with deficient air may do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a **diesel-electric locomotive TEM-2**.

[image: Diesel-electric locomotive TEM-2]

The more powerful modification of TEM-1 diesel locomotives.
In turn, TEM-1 locomotive is developed on the basis of TE-1 locomotives.
The TE-1 is soviet copy of American Locomotive Company RSD-1.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALCO_RSD-1

[image: ALCO_RSD-1]

> Does it have an official name?

"мотовоз"

Comment: @uhoh In Soviet photos, another locomotive is visible.  Model TE-3 http://www.buran.ru/images/jpg/bbur163.jpg

Comment: That's really beautiful; two pairs of back-to-back engines, thanks!

Comment: Google translates "мотовоз" as 'motor vehicle'. I think uhoh is looking for the type designation, which is TEM-2.

Comment: @Hobbes. I think that "an official name" not equivalent to "vehicle model". If we talk about the Russian dictionary, then this word does not really mean what is shown in this photo. But if you use Google to search for words in this context - "мотовоз"+"Байконур", you will find the local meaning of the word at the cosmodrome. For example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-qHJzbn7Ag https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AsBIm55cjqc Word "мотовоз" at Baikonur means a locomotive with one or more cars. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22P9x0qBByc Details of the Baikonur railway are described in this video.